# Offline application Cache HTML 5

Tags: html, manifest, offline-caching

I have developed a Facebook game, and used offline cache to store all my data in the application cache. I had around 100 images in the game, and I included all the images in the manifest file and font files. This included stylesheets, and JavaScript files as well.

Every thing is working fine, but the initial loading of all the content is taking a very long time ( > than 2 min).

Is there a way I can divide the content to another manifest in the second or third page of the game, and load some images in that manifest file? (I am having total 3 pages in my game and the game is developed using HTML and jQuery for client side, and PHP for server side )

How can I reduce the initial loading time, and make the game work in a smooth way without any further loading issues? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ZippyV images are all together 2MB and other resources like fonts, js, css etc are all another 1 MB

Comment: There not exists a way to implement an asynchronous download of the manifest file - as written in [w3.org][1] documentation.
They encourage to load the manifest in the "main thread" and present user interface asynchronously, using the js api of the manifest.


  [1]: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html

Comment: Maybe try reducing the size of files as much as you can, Minify everything, SVG, CSS, WebP can help you